# comparator sending out vcc value

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal-processing, comparator

I am having trouble using an comparator, the LM319N.
I am trying to get a 0.5V to -0.5V signal to raise to a 3.3V - 0V signal so i can read it using gpio pins on my micro controller. I tried a few setups
 using various input voltages (3.3V 5.0V and 13.5V) and all it does is setting the vcc value on the output. I put all my images in an imgur album because i cant put more than 2 links. [schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsACo.jpg)

first i tried picture one.
Put the negative input to ground an the positive to the signal. I tried many different voltages for the vcc+ and ground for the negative. But the out just gives the same as the vcc+ minus a bit. (+- 0.3-0.5 V).

After that i tried picture two.
I put the negitive lead to the negative signal. The signal has a positive and a negative. It comes from an xlr plug. I hoped that with the crossing of the two signals that the "bits" would come out at a more specific spot (or just come out at all). But same as last time just get the value of vcc+.

After that i tried picture three.
I read somewhere that the output was an open drain collector. As far as i am aware is that that means that it pretty much becomes a ground lead when it is active. So i added a pull-up. But again vcc+ was the output. I tried multiple values for R1. (10k, 1k and 500r).

after that i tried picture 4.
I thought an op-amp and an smitt trigger would do the trick to. Op-amp to elevate the signal to [3.3  -3.3] V and than cut it of to [3.3   0] V. with the smitt trigger. But even here the op-amp only outputs the vcc value. I am really at a loss. I appearantly dont get how i use an opamp. (explains why i keep failing my test on the subject). I really hope someone can enlightnen me with what i am doing wrong.

Also the signal in question is a Linear time code. which is usually transmitted over audio. And i tried multiple IC's so the case that it is just a bust ic is pretty much out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick search and linear time code and details were a bit sketchy but sounds like it is meant to be audio-like with bit rate from 960 to 2400 Hz being run as differential audio, presumably through an XLR connector.

I think the attached circuit will work well. Your existing LM319 comparator may not work very well at 3.3V. Either supply it with 5V but have its output pulled up to 3.3V to keep it 3.3V logic compatible or use a comparator that works at a 3.3V supply (like the LT1017). Also, if using LM319, check with your MCU datasheet to see if 0.5V is a valid logic low (usually called "Vih", input voltage logic low) since it cannot pull to GND, as other folks have noted.

You might want to add a resistor across the input if there is some sort of matching you need to do. Usually for audio, transmission line matching is not at all critical.

I like this design because it maintains the balance of the differential transmission line to keep it noise resistant. Let me know if you want an explanation of how it works. Hope this helps, -Vince

[image: Linear Time Code to Digital Out]

Comment: This works perfect. Resulting signal is 3.3V - 0.1V which is perfect because the mcu i use in question requires low to be below 0.54V.

Comment: Cool. Also, understand that I put in an intentional offset to bias it towards a "0" for noise immunity so there is a limit on how long the signal can stay a "1". This has to do with the RC time constant of the series caps and the resistors. For my quick 2 minute scan of SMPTE LTC protocol, this should not be a problem, but wanted to mention it just in case. Also, R5 can be removed if the comparator you choose has a push-pull output instead of open-drain/open-collector.

Answer (score 5):

The input voltage range of the LM319 does not extend to ground or below. The lowest valid input voltage is 1V above ground. Note also that the output is open collector so you do need a pull-up from output to positive rail.

Comment: I see. So in this case the op-amp solution would make more sense? Are there any obvious errors i made in my op-amp schematic?

Comment: Apart from the 741 being a donkey of a device you will have the same problem - it doesn't like input voltages getting to within about 2 V of either rail. If you use a -2V supply that you can use to take the -Vcc of the LM319 negative then it should work fine.

Comment: So to clarify. if i use an op-amp to create a inverting amplifier with a gain of -0.4 and put 5 volts in it and lead that to the -vcc of the lm319m and put an pull-up on the output it should work?

Comment: @Tom - An op amp (particularly a 741) is far worse than a 319. 741s should operate with power voltages in the +/-12 to +/15 volts. Your sample circuit simply will not work.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Thats about what i gathered from Andyaka. Now that i know that the 319 needs its inputs to be about 2V away from the leads i'm gonna try to feed it -2V on the -vcc like Andyaka recommended.

Comment: @Tom - Also note that you'll need to make sure the ground pin is tied to ground, and use a 1k pullup to V+ on the output.